# Updating sessions in PHP?

Tags: php, session

When a user logs in, it greets them with a message that includes their name and is retrieved by a session so:

```
<p>Welcome, 
  <a  href="profile.php"><?php echo $_SESSION["info"]["users_name"];?></a> 
     (<a  href="logout.php">Logout</a>)
</p>
```

(Stored in the "users_name" array is the first name and last name of the user which is retrieved from a table called "Users")

When they log in they can edit their profile, I have completed the UPDATE query and it works perfectly, however when the user changes their first name and last name they have to log out and log back in for it to show their updated first and last name in the "Welcome" message, how would I update this Session without destroying and starting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update `$_SESSION["info"]["users_name"]` with the same as you run your update query. Then it will be changed.

For example

```
$_SESSION['info']['users_name'] = $_POST['updated_username_from_profile_edit']
```

If you do this before you echo $_SESSION, it will show the updated content...

Please remember to sanitize user input before you handle it / store it into $_SESSION

Answer (score 3):

just do this after you execute the edit query in the database-

```
$_SESSION["info"]["users_name"] = 'New changed Name';
```